# How to use barcode scanner sensor in Honeywell EDA70 Android PDA Device

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am developing an app for PDA device (Honeywell EDA70) and i don't know how to access the physical Barcode scanner in it. Until now I only used barcode scanning using Camera not that physical sensor.

**What i have tried:**

1. Tried to search sample codes but didn't find any

**What i want:**

1. I'd like to know how to do barcode scanning with the physical sensor for that specific device, including any SDKs I need to download.
2. If possible, I'd like to have example code that implements scanning in such devices in general.

Comment: have you tried to contact the manufacturer ?

Comment: they didn't respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'am late, but atleast for someone else. Scanner should be like a keyboard - if you focus on any textfield and press scanning button, the barcode will appear.

Comment: dose it works like that? I didn't take the project because of the issue that I am facing

Comment: yes, it does. most of these hardware scanners are just external keyboards.

Comment: okay. thanks for your answer. this may be helpful for some other people as well.